# java program to use url specified in the mail

Tags: java

I am having a java coding in which i need to open a webpage.that webpage link is available in my mail id.i had programmed to get my mail message to get the webpage link.now that webpage link is stored in a string URL.after that i had included

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(URL));
```

after that program should be closed.but when i run the program .i cant get the webpage opened.
it shows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 0: "www.google.com"
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
    at Email.main(Email.java:53)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 0: "www.google.com"
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3086)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3044)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)
```

Comment: you shoud use complete address i.e. "https......"

Comment: You are probably missing the http://

Comment: String s =message[i].getContent().toString();
            String[] splitted = s.split("https://");
            String[] splitt=splitted[1].split("\n");
            
            String url = "https://" + splitt[0] ;
            System.out.println(url); these are the above statements to extract the content from the mail and to spilit the link from that.here i had includeed the https://

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [javadoc for URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html). The URI is expected to be in a certain format, with a scheme. You are missing the scheme.